# Regx for Domain with 'www' or without 'www'

Tags: javascript, php, regex, string, preg-match

I want to search **domain** name from given string.

> Lorem **www.example.in** ipsum #web-developer dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec *suraj@mishra.com* consequat sem eros, et volutpat **google.com** lacus dignissim ac. Pellentesque ac nisl et erat porta feugiat. +91-141-2561894 Vestibulum #web_designing sodales semper **stackoverflow.com**

*what I have tried*

```
(www.)?[^@]\w+\.+\w{2,3}
```

its return me 5 matches 
 `www.exa` `mple.in` `mishra.com` `google.com` `stackoverflow.com`
where I only want 3 bold matches.

can you guys please help me to find out what I am doing wrong ?

Here is a [RegEx101 test](https://regex101.com/r/knOchH/1/)

```js
console.log("Lorem www.example.in ipsum #web-developer dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec suraj@mishra.com consequat sem eros, et volutpat google.com lacus dignissim ac. Pellentesque ac nisl et erat porta feugiat. +91-141-2561894 Vestibulum #web_designing sodales semper stackoverflow.com".match(/(www.)?[^@]\w+\.+\w{2,3}/g))
```

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan for your edit!

Comment: YW. Links go stale so always better to post a [mcve] here at SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of possible ways (requires *PCRE*):

```
\b(?<!@)(?:www\.)?[^@\s]+\.\w{2,3}
```

- `\b(?<!@)` - ignoring *email* domains like `...@mishra.com`

https://regex101.com/r/knOchH/5